# How do I replace some number of phone number with * symbol?

Tags: php, number-formatting, phone-number

Let's say I have the phone number 0501234555 for which I want to put some * sign on some places. I want that my number should be in this form 050*****55. I want to do this in php.

Can anyone please suggest how to do it? Thanks.

Comment: "some place"? Where?

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but the main idea is there.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code if its solve your problem

```
$number = '0501234555'; 
echo  substr_replace($number,'*****',3,5); // 050*****55
```